# User gets always redirected

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to redirect the user to the homepage if there is no cookie set.

This is what I have tried:

**app-routing.modules.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] }
];
```

**login.guard.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import {SearchComponent} from '../search/search/search.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private searchComponent: SearchComponent) {
  }
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): any {
      this.searchComponent.hasAccess().then(result => {
        return result;
      });
    }
}
```

**search.components.ts**

```js
hasAccess() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.login.hasCookie(this.cookieService.get('login')).subscribe(hasCookie => {
      if (hasCookie === 1) {
        return new Promise(() => {
          this.login.getCookie().subscribe(cookieFromServer => {
            if (cookieFromServer === this.cookieService.get('login')) {
              return resolve(true);
            } else {
              return resolve(false);
            }
          });
        });
      }
      return resolve(false);
    });
  });
}
```

The output of `result` is either `true` or `false` (I have tested both of them). 
No matter if it's `true` or `false`, the user gets ALWAYS redirected.

If I replace

```
this.searchComponent.hasAccess().then(result => {
  return result;
});
```

with `return true`, then it works and the user will not be redirected.

Why would `return true;` work but not `return result;`?

Comment: When you log the `result` whats the value? could you add that to the question please

Comment: try by adding a return before  this.searchComponent ...

Comment: @C_Ogoo the output of `result` is always either false or true. I have updated my question.

Comment: @AbelValdez if I try it with `return true;`, then it works. I have updated my question.

Comment: my answer was the correct one right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is with your `canActivate` method as it does not return anything. Just by adding `return` to `this.searchComponent.hasAccess()` should solve your problem. Your code can be like this:

```
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): any {
      return this.searchComponent.hasAccess().then(result => {
        return result;
      });
    }
```

After this angular will know to wait till promise gets resolved.